# SizeChanged event not fired for manually created UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is a very simple WPF `UserControl`:

```
public class ControlBase : UserControl
{
    public ControlBase()
    {
        this.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(OnSizeChanged);
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Doing something here
    }
}
```

I noticed that when I create instance of `ControlBase` manually there is no `SizeChanged` event fired when I change `Width`/`Height` properties.

```
ControlBase ctrl = new ControlBase();
ctrl.Width = 100; // <--- no event fired
```

How do I fix it?

In my application I'm using WinForm's UserControls and WPF's UserControls and I want to treat them equally. SizeChanged event in WinForm's controls causes no troubles. Is there a way to configure WPF's UserControls to act the same way?

Comment: Maybe you have to add it to the parent first?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 - That will sure do the trick. But in my case I do not have any parent panel or form - I just use created controls to get some of their characteristics. Is there a way to make WPF control work just like WinForms's controls without adding it to some parent control?

Comment: @G.Y - no, I made a mistake while extracting code from my application. Thank you. I have updated my code sample.

Comment: And for getting the UserControl's layout done, call its Measure and Arrange methods.

Comment: @Clemens - I case of using Measure and Arrange methods I would have to differ WPF controls from WinForms controls. Is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: No, it isn't (afaik). Layout has to be done.

Comment: @Clemens - I mean - is it possible to move Measure and Arrange methods to the WPF's control? Or some thing like that? So application would not have to worry about it?

Comment: Maybe write an extension method for both kinds of controls, with otherwise identical signature.

Comment: @Clemens - thank you. I was afraid you would say that. So now I would have to treat WPF and WinForms controls separately.